# Scala Play 2.3 framework Json validate recursively

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have json which is having same structure in field repeating.

```
case class RuleJson(`type`: String, attribute: Int, operator: Option[String], value: String, is_value_processed: String, aggregator: String, conditions: RuleJson)


object RuleJson  {  
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[RuleJson]
}
```

So the conditions key will have same RuleJson case structure. (though optional)

I am getting "No implicit Reads for models.RuleJson available." error.

My JSON is

```
{
    "type": "salesrule/rule_condition_combine",
    "attribute": null,
    "operator": null,
    "value": "1",
    "is_value_processed": null,
    "aggregator": "all",
    "conditions": [
        {
            "type": "salesrule/rule_condition_product_subselect",
            "attribute": "qty",
            "operator": "==",
            "value": "5",
            "is_value_processed": null,
            "aggregator": "all",
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "type": "salesrule/rule_condition_product",
                    "attribute": "quote_item_price",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "200",
                    "is_value_processed": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So if you see condition field is repeating, how do I validate such JSON in play scala 2.3?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't use the `Json.reads` macro because of a bug on recursive types. You'll have to write your own Reads manually. See: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2625

Comment: So I cannot parse a Json which is recursive and I don't know how many level it has?

Comment: You can build a `Reads` using the [json combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Recursive-Types)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Dimitri , can you please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482488/scala-dynamic-datatype-and-operators?noredirect=1 I need your help

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to change your case class so it actually matches the data you want to read (e.g. make optional values `Option[String]` etc) and then to use the `lazyRead[T]` functions to read values using the `Reads` you are currently constructing. Here's a case class (altered as appropriate) which works for your data:

```
case class RuleJson(
  `type`: String,
  attribute: Option[String],
  operator: Option[String],
  value: String,
  isValueProcessed: Option[Boolean],
  aggregator: Option[String],
  conditions: Seq[RuleJson]
)

object RuleJson {
  implicit val reads: Reads[RuleJson] = (
    (__ \ "type").read[String] and
    (__ \ "attribute").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "operator").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "value").read[String] and
    (__ \ "is_value_processed").readNullable[Boolean] and
    (__ \ "aggregator").readNullable[String] and
    (__ \ "conditions").lazyReadNullable[Seq[RuleJson]](Reads.seq(RuleJson.reads))
      .map(opt => opt.toSeq.flatten)
  )(RuleJson.apply _)
}
```

Two things to notice here:

- `conditions` is defined as a `Seq[RuleJson]`, but since it might not exist at all in the source JSON it's read as an optional value and the empty case mapped to an empty sequence
- since we're defining a reader for a recursive structure we use `lazyReadNullable` for the list of conditions and pass it an explicit reference to the `Reads` we are currently constructing. If we were not to use the `lazy...` variant the reads might crash with a null pointer error, since it makes a reference to something not yet defined (the `lazy` variants basically use Scala call-by-name parameters which aren't evaluated until they're needed.)