# Scala dynamic datatype and operators

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a json which will send me 3 fields.

attribute

operator

value

**for example:**

attribute:total

operator: >=

value:1000

In scala I want to compare that field_name value, against that condition_value, according to that operator

```
 if($cart[$field_name][$operator][$condition_value]) 
//means if(cart['total']>=100)
    return true
    else
    return false
```

Operators will be dynamic. 
Datatype of values will be dynamic, for example condition_value can be string or number. Can I achieve it in scala / play framework?

sample scala code of what I am trying to do (non working), rule is my input

```
val operator=rule.operator
     val datatype="Int"
             if((cart.\(rule.attribute.get)).as[datatype](operator)rule.value.as[datatype])
                return true;
             else
                return false;
             }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. Treat the json as weakly typed map, e.g. `JsObject` in spray-json, and use the functions there. What did you try, and what specific problems did you have? I don't know what kind of language you're trying to write in your code example, but it's definitely not scala.

Comment: Its PHP example. I am coding in play framework 2.0. Can you give me example using play framework json parse class? I want to have datatypes and operator dynamic, so I don't need to write match case statement for each datatype and operator

Comment: I have updated question with non working scala code, to give you better idea of what I am trying to get.